# Selection by attribute from list

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute, list

I need to select a layer with all attributes while the selection comes from a table. With my code I get only empty feature classes and emtey Excel files. The tab_list Elements are the selection value. If Name2 = Name1 the selection should starting.

```
 field = ["SHAPE_Length", "SHAPE_Area"]

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(workspace + "\\" + gdb + "\\" + "Verknuepfung", "selectlayer")

bet_tab_v_list = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(convert_table, ["Name1"])]
s_cur = arcpy.da.SearchCursor("selectlayer", ["Name2"])

tab_list = set(bet_tab_v_list)

counter = 1 
for elm in tab_list:
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("selectlayer", "NEW_SELECTION", "Name2 =' {}  '")
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("selectlayer", speicherpfad + "\\" + gdb + "\\" + text_pruefung(elm))
    arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(workspace + "\\" + gdb + "\\" + text_pruefung(elm), workspace + "\\" + gdb,"var")
    arcpy.DeleteField_management(workspace + "\\" + gdb + "\\" + "var", field)
    arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion(workspace + "\\" + gdb + "\\" + "var", workspace + "\\" + elm + ".xls")
    arcpy.Delete_management(workspace + "\\" + gdb + "\\" + "var")
    arcpy.AddMessage("Round" + str(counter))
    counter+=1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is selecting for all values `{}` in field `Name2`.

`arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("selectlayer", "NEW_SELECTION", "Name2 =' {}  '")`

Try this:

`arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("selectlayer", "NEW_SELECTION", "Name2 ='{}'".format (elm))`